# invalid use of registers

Tags: assembly, x86-16

```
VElist     dw 2,40;      
           dw 3,55;      
           dw 4,70;      
           dw 5,60;      
           dw 6,70;    
           dw 7,80;     
           dw 8,170;    
           dw 9,120;   
           dw 1,56;
```

I'm trying to add all this numbers that are the second number in this array of number pairs, ex:40,55,70
I typed

```
mov cx,des
sub cx,beg
mov ax,0
mov di,Beg
add ax,VElist[4*di-1]
```

where my program allowed us to enter the Variable "beg" and "des" between 1 to 0.

But the assembler keeps telling me the error information :invalid use of registers at  add ax,VElist[4*di-1].

I can't see I did any where wrong, I'll be thankful if anyone can help me solve this question:))

Comment: There's no SIB byte when using 16-bit addressing, so you can't do things like `di*4`.

Answer (score 1):

The address mode `VElist[4*di-1]` is not valid.
There is no scale in any of the 16-bit addressing modes.

---

Here a list of the available 16-bit addressing modes:

> [BX+SI]
>       [BX+DI]
>       [BP+SI]
>       [BP+DI]
>       [SI]
>       [DI]
>       disp16
>       [BX]
>       [BX+SI]+disp8
>       [BX+DI]+disp8
>       [BP+SI]+disp8
>       [BP+DI]+disp8
>       [SI]+disp8
>       [DI]+disp8
>       [BP]+disp8
>       [BX]+disp8
>       [BX+SI]+disp16
>       [BX+DI]+disp16
>       [BP+SI]+disp16
>       [BP+DI]+disp16
>       [SI]+disp16
>       [DI]+disp16
>       [BP]+disp16
>       [BX]+disp16

Refer to [Intel manual 2](https://www-ssl.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/manuals/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-instruction-set-reference-manual-325383.pdf) section 2.1 for further information.